# Is there a way to automatically deliver rucksacks to your homestead from a vehicle?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

In the first State of Decay, you could automatically deposit all rucksacks from your trunk to your homestead by parking the vehicle in the parking space outside of your homestead.  Is there any way of doing that in State of Decay 2? I tried parking in the space designated but nothing happened and it doesn’t look like I can upgrade the parking space to do this. Right now I’m having to make 6 trips back and forth.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that in the first game.....man i wasted a ton of time with supplies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you park in the spot, and open the trunk, you can transfer one item at a time without walking back and forth. On Xbox, it's RT. On PC it is T for transfer.